# Graficar rectas y funciones en R

Tags: r, funciones, function, plot

quiero graficar una hiperbola (x^2+1) y una recta (y=-1) en R pero solo gráfica la función cuadrática no la recta. Cuando intento graficar solo la recta me aparece el siguiente error:

```
`Error in plot(fun, from = -5, to = 5, ylim = c(-8, 8), col = "red") : 
 objeto 'fun' no encontrado`
```

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
'fun <- function(x){x^2+1}
 fun2 <- function(y){y=-1}
 plot(fun,from=-5,to=5,ylim=c(-8,8),col="red")
 par(new=TRUE)
 plot(fun2,from=-5,to=5,ylim=c(-8,8),col="red")'
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que en una misma gráfica aparezca la hipérbola y la recta.

Answer (score 1):

> Error in plot(fun, from = -5, to = 5, ylim = c(-8, 8), col = "red") :
> objeto 'fun' no encontrado

El error es simple, no se encuentra la función `fun`, en el código que compartiste se observa una comilla simple delante de `fun`, no se si es un error tipográfico, pero lo cierto es que al momento del hacer `plot`, `fun` no existe.

De cualquier manera, tienes otro problema, por el cual seguramente no logras dibujar la recta:

```
fun2 <- function(y){y=-1}
```

La función tiene dos problemas (1) asigna un valor a `y` pero no retorna ningún valor y (2) de cualquier forma, si retornaramos -1, estaríamos devolviendo un vector con un único elemento, cuando en realidad deberíamos retornar un vector del mismo tamaño de `x`. Si corregimos esto, debería funcionarte:

```
fun <- function(x){x^2+1}
fun2 <- function(x){x*0 + -1}

plot(fun,from=-5,to=5,ylim=c(-8,8),col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fun2,from=-5,to=5,ylim=c(-8,8),col="red")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! crack!